# High cpu consumption due to a jquery regex patch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am going to work on a project developped by someone else. I don't have any contact with this guy.
I noticed a very high cpu consumption by the browser when the page is loaded.

After some investigations, i think that the problem comes from a patch of jquery regex but I don't clearly understand the goal of this patch and the cause of this cpu consumption.

```
jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function(elem, index, match) {
   var matchParams = match[3].split(',');
   var validLabels = /^(data|css):/;
   var attr = {
      method:
         matchParams[0].match(validLabels) ? matchParams[0].split(':')[0] : 'attr',
         property: matchParams.shift().replace(validLabels,'')
   };
   var regexFlags = 'ig';
   var regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''), regexFlags);
   return regex.test(jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property));
};
```

I have seen that this method was constanly called.

I have several calls to regex like this one.

```
$(':regex(id,DelCompo.*$)').livequery('click',function(e) {
   //...
}
```

If I comment them, the cpu consumption seems to be normal. Of course, some features are broken.

I think the problem comes from this new regex function. Is it correct?
What would be the best way to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Apparently `$(':regex(id,DelCompo.*$)')....` will iterate over all DOM nodes only to filter few of them. Did you try adding a prefix such as `$('a:regex(id,DelCompo.*$)')` or `$('input:regex(id,DelCompo.*$)')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, I fixed it by not using regex in the jquery selector. I guess that this was not the right choice for my document.