# Search row with highest number of cells in a row with colspan

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the efficient way to search highest number of cells in big table with numerous colspan (merge cells ** colspan should be ignored so in below example highest number of cells is 4 in first row). Is it  js/jquery with reg expression or just the loop with bubble sorting. I got one link as below explainig use of regex is it ideal way ... can someone suggest pseudo code  for this.

[High cpu consumption due to a jquery regex patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990653/high-cpu-consumption-due-to-a-jquery-regex-patch)

```
<table width="156" height="84" border="0" >
    <tbody>
        <tr style="height:10px">
            <td width="10" style="width:10px; height:10px"/>
            <td width="10" style="width:10px; height:10px"/>
            <td width="10" style="width:10px; height:10px"/>
            <td width="10" style="width:10px; height:10px"/>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:10px">
            <td width="10" style="width:10px; height:10px" colspan="2"/>
            <td width="10" style="width:10px; height:10px"/>
            <td width="10" style="width:10px; height:10px"/>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:10px">
            <td width="10" style="width:10px; height:10px"/>
            <td width="10" style="width:10px; height:10px"/>
            <td width="10" style="width:10px; height:10px" colspan="2"/>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:10px">
            <td width="10" style="width:10px; height:10px" colspan="2"/>
            <td width="10" style="width:10px; height:10px"/>
            <td width="10" style="width:10px; height:10px"/>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var rowWithMaxCells = $("tr").get().reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.children.length > b.children.length ? a : b;
});

console.log(rowWithMaxCells);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/M58sX/)

**Edit**

```
function getRowWithMaxCells(table) {
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"),
        i = rows.length,
        maxIdx = -Infinity,
        curMax = -Infinity;

    while (i--) {
        if (curMax <= rows[i].children.length) {
            curMax = rows[i].children.length;
            maxIdx = i;
        }
    }

    return rows[maxIdx];
}
```

Just for the sake of completeness a version which should work in all browsers :)
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KLTyR/)

Comment: Wow, that's beastly. +1 for wicked awesome use of `.reduce()`. But it should be noted that this will probably fail in pre-ES5 browsers without some sort of `reduce()` shim.

Comment: I really like the new methods :)

Comment: use of reduce is something surprising for me as well & it is great... huge Thx Andreas for letting us now..but is it efficient than conventional loop or has any overhead would be to check .. i used jquery loop as below which seems more compact...  Example :- http://jsfiddle.net/K5vkR/ (tcols is max# of td/cells)

Comment: n = number of rows; `.reduce(...)` = n - 1 function calls; your example: 2*n function calls (`$(qtblRows[i])` and `.find("td")`). For further performance comparisons have a look at [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com)

Comment: I had to adjust your example a little bit to get the same result (row with max cells not number of max cells) but these adjustments are very small and won't have any noticeable effect on the performance. With the latest chrome (v21) the `.reduce()` version is ten times faster. [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/array-reduce-vs-jquery-each)

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this issue by using [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector).

I'd do a simple loop and look for `./tr/td[index]` until it came back as `null`.  Then max would be `index-1`

You could do something similar with [.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName).